# I want to name a file with the name of a directory in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to create files with the name of it's antepenultimate directory:

Example:
Directory: a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j

The name of folder h is different for each case.

So I created an array

```
array=(/ a / b / c / d / e / f / g / * / * / *)
len=${#array[@]}

for (( q=0; q<$len; q++ ));    
do 
    cd ${array[$q]}
    sleep 1
    mri_convert 0001*.dcm RAW.nii.gz #--->this line is just converting the format of file 0001*.dcm in to file RAW.nii.gz
done
```

This code is working but I want the file RAW.nii.gz to be named h_RAW.nii.gz

I tried doing this:

```
s1="${array%/*/*}"
$ echo "${s1##*/}"
```

and then:

```
mri_convert 0001*.dcm ${s1##*/}_RAW.nii.gz
```

but it's not working.

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: That can't be how you create `array` in your actual code.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, your loop will start at the root `/` and go to `/a`, then back to the root `/` and to `/b`, and continue like that...but what is `*`? How are you resolving that? Also how are you ever going to find a directory which resides at least 3 levels deep in order to do what you plan on doing?

Comment: This is how you can find the name of a directory which resides 3 levels deep: 
s1="${array%/*/*}"
$ echo "${s1##*/}"   Where array is a vector that contains a set of directories

Answer (score 2):

How about

```sh
cd /a/b/c/d/e/f/g
for dir in *; do
    [[ -d $dir ]] || continue
    for subdir in "$dir"/*/*/; do (
        # doing this in a subshell so we don't need to "undo" this cd
        cd "$subdir"
        mri_convert 0001*.dcm "${dir}_RAW.nii.gz"
    ); done
done
```

Comment: I think you mean `continue` and not `next` ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I can help. I'm not exactly sure of the details of what you're trying to do (mainly because the code you posted:

```
for (( q=0; q do cd ${array[$q]} sleep 1 mri_convert 0001*.dcm RAW.nii.gz
```

is not syntactically correct. So, that can't be what you're actually doing.

Just a hint of how i would approach a problem like this:

```
for path6 in /a/b/c/*/*/*
do
    path5="${path6##*/}"
    path4="${path5##*/}"
    name4="${path4%/*}"
    echo "Processing ${path4}"
    mriconvert "${path6}"/0001*.dcm "${path6}/${name4}_RAW.nii.gz"
done
```